# Shrink table cell height despite content

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping there is a way to shrink the height of a td so that the height is exactly what I want, example 6px when it is holding 11px text. I'm envisioning being able to see the top half of the cell content.

The reason I don't want to just set the div height is I want each row to be the same height, and there are cells spanning rows so the div would be cutting off content to one cell when it should be able to expand to the two cells. I hope that makes some sense...

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="height: 0px; width: 0px;">
            </th>
            <th style="width: 25px;">
            </th>
            <th style="width: 25px;">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 6px;">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Some table data</div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <div>
                    Some data that is two rows high</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 6px;">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Some more data</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restrict the table cells' height but you can enforce height on the immediate `<div>`s:

```
td > div {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 6px;
}
```

Comment: But then the double row will also get cut off at 6px which is what I don't want. I should mention that this table is getting generated dynamically so I don't know which cells are going to be spanned. Since you can't span divs I need to use the td height.

Comment: In that case you can exclude those cells that span, something like  `td:not([rowspan]) > div`.  You'd still have to decide on a max height for those spanning divs though.

Comment: That's good but wouldn't handle the spanning cells which could span x rows.

Comment: On second thought maybe I don't need to worry about the spanning cells because I know they'll be taller than the content. I can use the td height for those cells and the div height for the one row cells. I'll have to test it out but I think that will work. Thanks